# Creating unconventional charts using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create the following chart in python pandas:
[image]

in the Tables folder Limits.txt determines the minimum and maximum for every delta_n limit. DUTs.txt contains the values for every delta_n,

you can download it here:

[Tables.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1ijz4fmw08ioym/Tables.zip?dl=0)

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` and `bokeh` are better options for this. Pandas `plot` is just `matplotlib` -- [source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

In bokeh, you can plot the bars with [vbar](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.vbar)

And you can plot the lines with [line](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.line)

Bokeh tutorials to get started: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/index.ipynb#Tutorial